# Populating an array using Parse queries (Swift)

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to populate an array with a query from my parse database. When I try to print out the content of the array, I get an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error. It doesn't seem like I'm properly appending new elements into my array, I'd appreciate any sort of tips

```
func loadSampleTasks() {

    tasks = [Task]()
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Task")
    query.whereKey("TaskName", equalTo: "kenny")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock() {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil && objects != nil {
            self.parseResults(objects!)
            print(self.tasks) // this prints out Kenny object as expected
        }
    }
    print(tasks) // prints an empty array
}

func parseResults(objects: Array<PFObject>){

    for object in objects { //looping through returned data
        print("no error in Parse lookup")
        let parseResult1 = Task(name: object["TaskName"] as! String)
        parseResult1?.completed = object["Completed"] as! Bool
        print("Parse result in object loop: \(parseResult1!.name)")
        tasks.append(parseResult1!)
    }

}
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: This is happening because you're getting your parse results in a closure, which means it may execute after the function itself has already returned.

Comment: What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

To what thefredelement said, "This is happening because you're getting your parse results in a closure, which means it may execute after the function itself has already returned." Before this happens, though, it won't work properly and you'll come back with that error.

Comment: I don't quite understand why there would be an error. It seems like I'm calling print after the closure so it should be fine?

Comment: Ha, I'm too late! I took a lunch break and then tried to scout around for the answer and found that I received the same error in fake scripts after I was calling something outside of its respective function. But it looks like you already got to that point, so I'm a tad too late. Glad you got it to work! :)

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. I had to tableView.reloadData() within the closure. Thank you so much for the help!